# Is there a Python interface to the X11 session management protocol library (SMlib)?

Tags: python, x11

I'm looking for a Python interface to the X Windows session management protocol library (SMlib). I need to have a Python application for the Linux desktop (not window-manager- or desktop-environment-specific) register itself as part of the user's X Windows session without tying it to a specific window manager or desktop environment. Does such a thing exist and does anyone have a name or web site for it?

I have the documentation for `cffi` to write the wrapper myself if I absolutely have to and I can find SMlib wrappers for other languages like Ruby, I'd simply prefer to use an existing package if one already exists. To date my searches return primarily results for either SMS messaging or HTTP sessions for Web applications/services, nothing related to X Windows or SMlib/ICElib.